# Alternative solution for accessing labels from other class using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, object, timer, constructor

I have two classes main class called `Dmi` we have a frame and a label in this.
I have implemented a timer in this class. In the `actionPerformed` I have called a thread called AB in AB class.

Now I want to update the label (twice with delay in between for this I placed `lbl.setText()` infinite while loop) from the thread. For this I have created an object lh and referenced from AB class. To create the object I have to write.
**Dmi lh=new Dmi()** which calls the constructor in that a new timer starts and a new frame since it is in a while loop frames go on creating. Any alternative solution for this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Dmi implements ActionListener
{

Timer tim;
JFrame frame;
JLabel lbl;
Thread th;

Dmi()
{
    // AB=new Thread();
    frame=new JFrame("abc");
    lbl=new JLabel("count");
    frame.add(lbl);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    tim=new Timer(1000,this);
    tim.start();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    while(true)
    {
        new AB().start();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Dmi();
}
}
class AB extends Thread
{
Thread th1=new Thread();
public void run()
{
    Dmi lh=new Dmi();

    lh.lbl.setText("abc");
    try
    {
        th1.sleep(300);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    lh.lbl.setText("def");
}
}
```

Comment: You have a post card, and you want a friend to write a word on this post card. Do you let your friend buy another post card, or do you give him your post card? Same here: you need to give the label to update to the new AB(). So, `new AB()` must be replaced by `new AB(this.lbl);`

Comment: That said, the rest of the code doesn't make sense. After 1 second, the timer is triggered. And it then creates and start an infinity of threads, each of them trying to update the text of the label after 300 milliseconds. Not to mention that you may not touch to a Swing component from a background thread. Only from the event dispatch thread. Why don't you use update the text from the timer directly? That's what it's for.

Comment: I think If i update without thread while loop continues infinitely and label will not get updated because the label will get updated only after one timer iteration. I think ...

Comment: @ JB Nizet  can you elobarate the answer if i try     new AB(this.lbl).start   it does not compile.

Comment: Because you must of course make it compile: the constructor of AB must take the label to update as argument, store it in an instance variable, and update it, instead of creating a new Dmi.